# My .jsp AJAX call is returning the code from my Servlet controller instead of executing it

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have an index.jsp calling a Java controller which performs an operation and returns a result. All the code is sitting in a server. So I have Tomcat running on the server and call the index page from my local machine. The problem is that the AJAX that calls the controller is bringing back the whole Java code instead of executing it in the server and bringing back the result. So I'm literally getting

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class LoginController extends HttpServlet {

public LoginController()
{
    super();
}
```

etc. This is the Ajax code:

```
function loadRows()
{
     var review_ID = location.search.split('review=')[1];

     $.ajax({
            url : "../src/mvcdemo/controllers/LoginController.java",
            type : "post",
            data : {
                "reviewID" : review_ID 
            },
            success : function(data) {
                alert(data);
            ...
            }
     });
```

PS: Java IS installed in the server, and the whole project works fine if I run it from my localhost. The problem is in the communication between the local machine and the server. Also, when running it on my localhost, the URL is just "LoginController" but when running it on the server it was not finding the file, so I had to use the relative path and add the ".java" at the end for it to work, I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Thanks in advance for any info!

EDIT:

I am using web.xml to define my Servlets, this is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
   <display-name>MVCDemo</display-name>
   <servlet>
      <description></description>
      <display-name>LoginController</display-name>
      <servlet-name>LoginController</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>mvcdemo.controllers.LoginController</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>LoginController</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/LoginController</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <servlet>
      <description></description>
      <display-name>UpdateController</display-name>
      <servlet-name>UpdateController</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>mvcdemo.controllers.UpdateController</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet>
      <description></description>
      <display-name>SubmitController</display-name>
      <servlet-name>SubmitController</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>mvcdemo.controllers.SubmitController</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
```

Comment: .java is basically an uncompiled text file with java source in it... it compiles to a .class file.

Comment: Regardless the name of the file has nothing to do with it but ratheryour servlet mappings do..... Are you using Servlet 3.0 annotations or web.xml?

Comment: `../src/mvcdemo/controllers/LoginController.java` why does that file even exist on the server (it shouldn't)? How have you deployed it?

Comment: The file is sitting on that location in the server. Where do you recommend to have it instead? @Neilos

Comment: I recommend that you do not have that file on the server at all... It is not supposed to be there. You should only deploy a pre-compiled application (which would contain .class files in binary format). Java is a compiled language http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiled_language and the .java file is the uncompiled source. The uncompiled source is not run in the JVM at all so it should not be on the server. An exception to this is .jsp files which compile to servlets (from source) when they are first run. Please read up on this so you understand.

Comment: @Neilos I have the code back as it was, calling `url: "LoginController"` which works on my local machine but not on the server. I definitely think that the web.xml is not getting loaded at all but I'm not sure how to include it. I was trying to include as an HTML link element, the same way you include css files `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">` but no luck

Comment: That is not the way that the web.xml is loaded. What web container are you using? Tomcat?

Comment: Add your servlet mappings to `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml` or whatever the equivelent is... It should be located in the conf directory of the tomcat installation (ie. `$CATALINA_BASE`)... by default... unless you have changed it.

Comment: Note: The web.xml is used as configuration when the web container starts up... it is not included in the markup at all... it is server configuration.

Comment: @Neilos I just added all three servlets and the one servlet-mapping I have up in the code, but it still can't find the LoginController. Could it be that I'm doing something wrong with what I have on the web xml? The way I'm defining the servlets or the servlet mapping to LoginController?

Comment: I didn't actually check them but assumed that if they are working on your local machine then they should work on the server. Please come to IRC, you can use https://kiwiirc.com/client i can chat to you easier there.

Comment: My bad, add the mappings to the web.xml under your apps WEB-INF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong but your jsp is not calling the controller.

**Solution 1**

Anyway try this using servlet 3.0 annotations (not tested):

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/login")
public class LoginController extends HttpServlet {

    public LoginController() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        // do whatever it is you want
    }

}
```

Then

```
$.ajax({
        url : "/login",
        type : "post",
        data : {
            "reviewID" : review_ID 
        },
        success : function(data) {
            alert(data);
        ...
        }
 });
```

**Solution 2**

If you cannot use servlet 3.0 annotations (which are really useful and more intuitive than web.xml)

Then you will have to use web.xml

You need to make sure that your web.xml is being loaded by the server correctly.

Comment: My jsp is calling the controller but it's bringing back the code that the controller has, instead of running it in the server. I tried adding the @WebServlet("/login") but no luck

Comment: Your jsp is not calling the controller.. I think what you mean is that the jsp contains some javascript that is used by the browser to call the LoginController servlet. Otherwise I do not know why you are using  that url in the jQuery ajax function. Is this incorrect?

Comment: Also what server are you running? does it support Servlet 3.0 annotations? How have you been defining the servlets up until now? Do you define them in web.xml?

Comment: When you use `@WebServlet("/login")` and try that URL what response do you get? 500, 404...?

Comment: I added the content of my web.xml as an EDIT

Comment: And yes, the jsp has a jQuery AJAX block that calls the LoginController Servlet. I am running this on a Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

Comment: Ok good. The URL `blah/.../LoginController.java` is certainly not the correct URL. It would seem that you are defining the servlet correctly such that you should use `url : "/LoginController"` (that is the correct URL). But maybe your web.xml is not being deployed to the server correctly. When using `url : "/LoginController"` do you get a 404 response?

Comment: when I use /LoginController my AJAX's error function gets calledm which redirects to an error.jsp I created

Comment: Note that the mapping `/LoginController` points to a compiled "servlet-class" located at `mvcdemo.controllers.LoginController` NOT the .java file (which is a text file)

Comment: Ok i need to know what error though... In your browser open developer tools (normally F12) and go to network. Then try to login and tell me what type of HTTP response you get (500 is internal server error, 404 is not found, 200 is ok etc...) I expect it is a 404.

Comment: how do I know that web.xml is playing a part in the process? I mean, finding out if it actually is being called at all

Comment: What I expect is happening is that your web.xml is not being deployed properly and your servlet mappings are not being applied. I don't know how to check that it is deployed correctly other than checking your servers settings (I'm not familiar with Windows Server 2012)

Comment: A 404 indicates that the web.xml is not loading properly and your servlet mappings are not being applied